# android, MediaScanner vs FileObserver for monitoring media file created

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-mediascanner, fileobserver

What is the best option (MediaScanner/FileObserver) to monitor couple of paths (both internal and external memory of device) for media files being created.

I need to get a event when ever a media file is being created in folder that is being monitored.

-Thanks & regards,
Manju

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Pedram, It is MediaScanner ! This is bcoz you get complete Media info in this and only need to filter for which you are intereseted. This can be achieved by setting filter in your query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `FileOberver` is a memory-killer approach. Consider a high volume of files. Rather `ContentObserver` seems a far better approach.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
        new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                Log.d("your_tag","Internal Media has been changed");
                super.onChange(selfChange);
                Long timestamp = readLastDateFromMediaStore(context, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // comapare with your stored last value and do what you need to do

            }
        }
    );
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
    new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.d("your_tag","External Media has been changed");
            super.onChange(selfChange);

            Long timestamp = readLastDateFromMediaStore(context, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // comapare with your stored last value and do what you need to do
        }
    }
);

private Long readLastDateFromMediaStore(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, "date_added DESC");
        PhotoHolder media = null;
        Long dateAdded =-1;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Long dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED));         
        }
        cursor.close();
        return dateAdded;
}
```

Probably a good idea to do this in a service (ever running)! You will also need to unregister in the `onDestroy()`

Warning: This only tells you when the MediaStore has been changed, it does not tellly anything specific about addition/deletion. For this, you may have to query the MediaStore to detect any change from your previous database or something.

Comment: So If i use this above code to a service class for notifying changes all the time(Ever running) then do i need to unregister Content Observer.

Comment: you should unregister in you onDestroy() in your ever running service. otherwise it will create memory leak.

Comment: But as it is ever runnig service its anyways going to create memory leak. So how to solve that?

Comment: why would it create a memory leak if you unregister? Could you explain the case you are thinking?

Comment: as my service is an ongoing service in background, unregister will never be called, unless service is destroyed due to reboot. So indirectly content observer is running every time.  So is that fine doing so

Comment: And one more thing how do we know using content observer which file is changed

Comment: yes that is fine. unregister is only for those specific case which is not very rare at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Read more about it on url above.

Comment: For the broadcast receiver, you need to add an intent filter, action in the manifest file. So in the above case what would you have it as?

Comment: How to get notified when any media file being created/moved in device internal/external memory on any path (not only on path dcim/camera but on any path in both internal/external memory of device)

Comment: @Ty221 which broadcast receiver intent will notify content provider media change